# Assigning to a variable with a computed name

Tags: syntax

I wish to assign about a dozen variables to complicated expressions. to ensure that the correct variable is assigned to the correct expression, I’d like to do something resembling

```
Do[
  MakeExpression[
    StringJoin[ Flatten[{"errY", Table["0", {n0}], Table["i", {ni}], Table["j", {nj}]}]], 
    StandardForm] = 
      <complicated expression in n0, ni, nj>;, 
  {nj, 0, 1}, {ni, 0, 2 - nj}, {n0, 0, 2 - ni - nj}]
```

E.g., test

```
MakeExpression["Xxxx", TraditionalForm] = 17
Xxxx
```

But assigning to the result of a `ToExpression` gives an error, and likewise `MakeExpression`. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Could you prepare minimal example of variables set and minimal "complicated expression in n0, ni, nj"? p.s. `ToExpression["XX = 17"];
XX`

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to SubValues. That might work, but wouldn’t compile to code as fast as just assigning it to a variable. Hence the desire to construct a variable name. 


An example of the “<complicated expression in n0, ni, nj>” has been requested. It is just the partial differential of a (different) complicated expression, wrt to three variables Y0, Yi and Yj, the number of times wrt to each being n0, ni, and nj. That partial differential will need to be computed many times, to machine precision being sufficient.